# Redis store millions of user events(with time to live) and retrieve when user login

Tags: redis

In my microservice, I am consuming kafka events for millions of users and when a user connect to my microservice, I need to provide the user specific events to connected user.

These events has time-to-live for 10 minutes and event structure is like this:

```
{
"id":"63cd45d4-c6c4-462a-a668-efe410ed619e",
"event":"propChn",
"refId":"01HCFRNFXH8VR90MAE21M0E7NQ"
}
```

I am considering Redis for this use-case, though I am new to Redis, I found that Sorted Set score by Timestamp would be better for my use case and I am considering to create Sorted set per user

```
ZADD user:1 <timestamp> <event1> <event2>
ZADD user:1 <timestamp> <event3>
```

As I have millions of users, I also need to make sure to cleanup events which are older than 10 minutes form each user's sorted set. **Sorted Set Time-to-live feature work on complete Set and not the events stored in the Set.**

Would there be any other efficient way to do this? Or is there any better way to cleanup events older than 10 minutes from all user's (Sorted)Sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot set a TTL on members of a sorted set, but there are two main ways to solve your problem.

1. You could have a job running periodically that removes old events.
2. You could extend the fetch logic to check if the user has expired events and remove them at the same time.

Exactly how you build your structure in Redis is up to you. You could use sorted sets, sets or hashes. For sets you could prefix members of `user:1` with the `timestamp` like `timestamp:event`. For hashes you could create records for `user:1` with `event` and `timestamp`.